# How to include ejb-jar.xml in .war

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-eap-6

My **ejb-jar.xml** contained in my war is not loaded when I package it inside an .ear
that I use on **jboss-eap-6.0.0/maven3**

Here is what my .ear file contains:

```
 -- lib/other.jar
 -- mesejbs.jar (with META-INF/ejb-jar.xml)
 -- monwar.war (with WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml)
```

Here is **mesejbs.jar/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <interceptor-class>monpackage.ejb.log.LogInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>monpackage.ejb.log.LogInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

**LogInterceptor is succcessfully invoked**.

Here is **monwar.war/WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">

    <interceptors>
        <!-- default interceptors -->
        <interceptor>
            <interceptor-class>monpackage.web.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>monpackage.web.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

**but SecurityInterceptor is never invoked !**

How do I activate `SecurityInterceptor`?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336727/ejb-3-1-application-deployed-as-war-only-what-about-ejb-jar-xml

Comment: Yes but my ejb-jar.xml is in the WEB-INF directory ! If I package a .war, all is right. But I need to package an ear :(

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've understood my problem.
It was not du to ejb-jar.xml in war. This is right.
It's du to CDI that is not enabled for both ejbModule and webModule.
Here are some explanations : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-778

so I just put my ejbModule in my webModule like this :

```
 -- lib/other.jar
 -- monwar.war (with WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml)
     -- WEB-INF/lib/mesejbs.jar (with META-INF/ejb-jar.xml)
```